# What does ((void (*)(int))-1) mean?

Tags: c

I just found this.

```c
// /usr/include/sys/signal.h // OS X
#define SIG_ERR ((void (*)(int))-1)
```

What does `((void (*)(int))-1)` part mean?

Is it different to

```c
#define SIG_ERR -1
```

?

Comment: Take a look at [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419483/casting-integer-to-function-pointer-in-signal-code-why-does-this-work)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is cast to a function-pointer:

```
((type) value)
```

Where type is `void (*)(int)` which is pointer to function accepting one `int` argument and returning `void`, which is actually is a signature of a signal handler:

```
typedef void (*sighandler_t)(int);
```

You may decode such types with `cdecl` tool or web-site: http://cdecl.org/

Comment: sorry, but [cdecl says this](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=%28%28void+%28*%29%28int%29%29-1%29).

Comment: Well @SouravGhosh, you're right, cdecl says there's a failure, but actually, myaut is totally correct according to me x). Guess cdecl is failing on that type of cast

Comment: @SouravGhosh; That's why I suggest people do not use cdecl.

Comment: @LeZohan68 I never said myaut is wrong, just the pointer to use cdecl is not that healthy, at some times :-)

Comment: @haccks ditto, sir. :-)

Comment: cdecl breaks at -1, but it parses `(void (*)(int))` well

Comment: @myaut yep, it can take a variable name, not a value after that. I made that comment just to make sure that anyone trying to _copy-paste_ the exact instruction and getting the error should not be confused. Hope you don't mind. :-)

Answer (score 2):

This is a cast of -1 into the function pointer which is expected as the type of SIG_ERR. Using -1 directly does not work at situations where the compiler needs the correct type.